# what are the relationship between O(nlogn)+O(n), O(nlogn) and O(nlogn + n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Intuitively, I thought the three expressions are equivalent.

For example, if an algorithm runs in `O(nlogn) + O(n)` or `O(nlogn + n)`(I'm confused), can I say that's an `O(nlogn)` algorithm?

what's the truth?

Comment: The actual explanation to why the answer is "yes" is mathematical and does not belong on Stack Overflow. Please move the question to CS Exchange

Comment: Do we really need to move every question that's not purely coding to CS Exchange ? ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can say that's an *O(nlogn)*.

When you are trying to estimate complexity of your algorithm you start with all parts (choose the worst operation which is in each part and ignore the fast ones - hey it's just an estimate). First part is nlogn and the second part is n.

Beacause you don't want/can/need it to be accurate.

O(nlogn + n) - or - O(nlogn) + O(n) -> nlogn grows faster then O(n) and therefore you can ignore O(n) -> O(nlogn)

It's all about how fast is the function growing - think about it like it's huge n then you'll see why you can ignore the slower growing function.

For more exact explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 1):

```
O(nlogn)= O(nlogn) + O(n) =O(nlogn+n)
```

in fact if `O(expression1) > O(expression2)` then you have:

```
O(expression1)= O(expression1) + O(expression2) =O(expression1+expression2)
```

in this case `expression1 = nlogn` and `expression2 = n`